# Why is iphone Simulator not rendering HTML5 page correctly?

Tags: iphone, html, ios-simulator

I have a page I am developing in .net using HTML5 intended for a WebView in an iphone App. The page looks just fine in Safari. When I load it in the iphone Simulator it is rendering as plain text, no styles or js loading. I thought it might be an issue with .net, but seeing as it works in Safari i am stumped. When I use the XHTML doctype it works just fine in the Simulator. Any ideas why this is occurring and what the fix may be? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the solution is just to provide the doctype. What else are you looking for?

Comment: the html5 doctype is just <!doctype html>. i am assuming maybe the iphone simulator has more sensitive parsing or something.. or it's old enough that it isn't recognizing this new type as valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it seems that the lovely .net mobile.browser file was setting the mime type for the simulator as xml. set it to xhtml and all is rosy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have problems rendering on the device? If not, don't worry about the Simulator, because it's not guaranteed to represent perfectly how the hardware works.